# Naming properties such that TagHelper can realize them

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Just reading a book on MVC Core 2.0 I came across this section where I create a new TagHelper

```
public class ButtonTagHelper: TagHelper  {
    public string BsButtonColor { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", $"btn btn-{BsButtonColor}");
    }
}
```

My question is about the naming of that property as **BsButtonColor**.  Specially the **Bs prefix**. I can't understand that when I continue reading to connect it to this explanation below.

[image]

Comment: The name of the property as it is written will be `bs-button-color`. MVC will inspect element that are using `bs-button-color` as attribute. The Bs prefix is just here to make sure you'll not get collision with other tag helpers. You can use any prefix as you want.

Comment: @CodeNotFound oh nice yes I saw in a few pages later he was using it like this:
<button bs-button-color="danger" type="submit">ADD</button>  and VS intellisense  even autocompleted it for me. Intresting. So there is some Convention for MVC that we type camel case like that, it knows to hypen it like that in Razor ?

Comment: yes it is a convention in Razor.